# Error: Makefile:7: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: assembly, makefile, nasm

I
I am trying to convert assembly into an .img file. but it will not work

```
ASM=nasm

SRC_DIR=src
BUILD_DIR=build

$(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img: $(BUILD_DIR)/main.bin
    cp $(BUILD_DIR)/main.bin $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img
    truncate -s 1440k $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img
    
$(BUILD_DIR)/main.bin: $(SRC_DIR)/main.asm
    $(ASM) $(SRC_DIR)/main.asm -f bin -o $(BUILD_DIR)/main.bin
```

I have tried changing the positions of the $ signs. I want to convert the asm file to a .img file.
I have ensured i have not made any space indents, i used only tabs.

Comment: In `makefile`-s tab characters are important. Did you edit your `makefile` with GNU [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) ?

Comment: I used Micro text editor

Comment: This is the single most common problem with makefiles.  There are 100's of answers to this exact same question on SO, not to mention other sites.  Did you google this error?  Or search SO?

Comment: You don't have to use GNU Emacs.  But you do need to use an editor that won't muck around with your TAB characters (convert them into spaces for example).

Comment: You don't need to use GNU emacs, but I do recommend trying it for an hour